# Flashing of ESP32-C3-Mini

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I have made a circuit to flash the ESP32, I have followed the circuit in the Devkit but still have some questions regarding  that. Can you please have a look and let me know if there should be any changes before going to board manufacturing.[image]